# if value table 1 row = 'confirm' and value table 2 row='Not sent' show button

Tags: php, mysql

if value table 1 row = 'confirm' and value table 2 row='Not sent' show button

```
<td><?= $row['numbershipping'] ?>
    <?php if($row['purchase']['numbershipping']==["Confirmed"]["Not Sent"]):?>
    <a href="shippingupdate.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_order'];?>"
    class="btn">View</a>
    <?php endif ?>
</td>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
</td>
              <?php $value1=$row['purchase'];
                    $value2=$row['numbershipping'];
              ?>
              <td><?= $value2 ?></td>
                <?php if(($value1=="Confirmed")||(!$value2=="Not Sent")):?>
                    <a href="shippingupdate.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_order'];?>" class="btn">View</a>
                <?php endif ?>
              </td>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).